# Cannot create notification when row is updated

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am using Laravel Pusher notification and able to add notification when the row is created but having difficulties when row is updated. Here is the code beneath

CategoryObserver

```
public function updated(Category $category)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    foreach($user->followers as $follower)
    {
        $follower->notify(new UpdateCategory($user, $category));
    }
}
```

And UpdateCategory

```
class UpdateCategory extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{

    return [
        'following_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'following_name' => Auth::user()->name,
    ];
}
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'read_at' => null,
        'data' => [
            'following_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'following_name' => Auth::user()->name,
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: Is your Events are Queueable?

Comment: "...having difficulties when row is updated" - What exactly are the difficulties? Is there an exception?

Comment: When a new row is added a notification is added to database but not when the row is updated. This is the difficulty. @AdnanMumtaz yess I used `use Queueable` in UpdateCategory

Comment: Can you add the constructor for your notification to your question?

Comment: Here you go. Only UpdateCategory has the constructor

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updated(Category $category)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    foreach($user->followers as $follower)
    {
        $follower->notify(new UpdateCategory($user, $category));
    }
}
```

//In your Notification

```
class UpdateCategory extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

public $user;
public $category;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user, Category $category)
{
    //
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->category = $category;
}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{

    return [
        'following_id' => $this->user->id,
        'following_name' => $this->user->name,
    ];
}
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'read_at' => null,
        'data' => [
            'following_id' => $this->user->id,
            'following_name' => $this->user->name,
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

You are using `Auth()` in a Queueable notifications which is not accessible. Remove Queueable trait from your Notification and  Try to Inject User object in Notifications class.

Comment: But he isn't using ```Auth``` in the notification, he's using it in the controller, to then pass in the User model. Which he is likely using in his other (working) event as well...

Comment: I also have created method in CategoryObserver which is working fine.

Comment: @OscarWilde have a look `Auth::user()->id,` he is using

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz Ah, I see where you're saying now. You should change the portion of code that you highlighted in your answer to showcase *that* part of his code. It does seem odd that he's already passing in the user object, but then getting it from Auth again inside... I requested to see the notification constructor. Maybe he isn't actually using the "$user" that he's passing in.

Comment: Your edit was faster! But good to see we both came up with the same code haha

Comment: Yeah, I didn't declare the variables haha, that's alright. Hopefully he accepts yours eventually. Not sure what else his issue would be.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't use the parameters you're passing into it. Instead, you're requesting them again within the notification.

`$follower->notify(new UpdateCategory(`**$user, $category**`));`

It doesn't seem like you need the category in there, but you should be using the $user like this.

```
///In your controller
$follower->notify(new UpdateCategory($user, $category));

//In UpdateCategory
public function __construct(User $user, Category $category) //Make sure these are "used" at the top
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->category = $category;
}

//Which enables you to use the user *within* the notification later
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{

    return [
        'following_id' => $this->user->id,
        'following_name' => $this->user->name
    ];
}
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id, //You also aren't really getting this anywhere? Is it supposed to be the category id?
        'read_at' => null,
        'data' => [
            'following_id' => $this->user->id,
            'following_name' => $this->user->name
        ],
    ];
}
```

I'm not sure if it is completely the issue at hand here, but it is definitely the proper way to use the User inside the notification.